# Windows network

Tags: 18.04, windows, windows-10, filemanager

I used to run my laptop on windows earlier. But, when I installed Ubuntu, I choose to replace Windows. I had a lot of soft wares installed in my Windows 10. I assumed that all of them got deleted and my laptop was empty again. 
I would like to understand what "Windows Network" means in this image:

[image: Screenshot of the file manager in my Ubuntu 18.04]

Comment: Also, when I try to open the "Windows Network" file, the following error message is displayed:"Failed to retrieve share list from server:No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

If you have other windows devices in your network you can discover them and share files and folders.

Check out this article if you want to share files from your ubuntu mahcine to other windows devices
https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/